# Copying data from every nth column to a new column

Tags: google-sheets

i have a sheet with data in i4,i11,i18,i25 etc; besides this data in every 7th cell of column i starting at i4 all the other cells in i column are blank(there is data in other columns i.e."a-h") I would like to copy the data from these cells in column i starting at i4 then every 7th cell in  a new column  n that has the data starting in n2.  I have tried an example I found here with a list of names with to solutions and can't get either to work.
=filter(I4:I, mod(row(I4:I)+1,7)=0)
=offset(I$4,7*(row()-1)-2,)

Thank you!

Comment: Can you share a copy of the sheets for a better understanding of the problem?

Answer (score 1):

it should be:

```
=FILTER(I4:I, MOD(ROW(I4:I)+3, 7)=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=QUERY(I4:I,"select * skipping 7")
```

The following should also work for your case

```
=QUERY(I2:I,"select * where I is not null")
```